# How do i get the list of items that are in array B (that is made up of objects) but are not in array A .?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**JavaScript :**

How do i get an array of items that are in array B (that is made up of objects) but are not in array A .
For example I have two arrays hackers and developers . Now I would like to get an array that has the developers who are not hackers : something like

```
resultOfDevelopersWhoAreNotHackers = [{
    name:'Paul',
    id:6
}];

var hackers = [
    {
        name:'Joy',
        id:2
    },
    {
        name:'Peter',
        id:3
    }
];

var developers = [
    {
        name:'Joy',
        id:2
    },
    {
        name:'Paul',
        id:6
    },
    {
        name:'Peter',
        id:3
    }
];
```

I have tried looping through both but it fills my array twice :

```
var resultOfDevelopersWhoAreNotHackers = [];
hackers.map((x)=>{

        coders.map((k)=>{
            if(k.id != x.id){
                resultOfDevelopersWhoAreNotHackers.push(x);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) tends to be useful for problems regarding the unions of arrays.

```js
// Input.
const hackers = [{name:'Joy',id:2},{name:'Peter',id:3}]
const programmers = [{name:'Joy',id:2},{name:'Paul',id:6},{name:'Peter',id:3}]

// Programmers Not Hackers.
const programmersNotHackers = (H, P) => {
  const s = new Set(H.map(h => h.id))
  return P.filter(p => !s.has(p.id))
}

// Output.
const output = programmersNotHackers(hackers, programmers)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through array B while checking the contents of Array A. Also look at the different kinds of joins in this blog post
[six join implementations in javascript](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/six-join-implementations-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link - Im checking it out